# unused variable with if condition

Tags: c, cs50

I have the test code below, where my program will allow input of a `float` number. There is a condition checking whether the float value is smaller than or equal to `1` but bigger than `0`. Then, variables `b` and `c` will be defined in one way. If the input is > `1`, `b` and `c` will defined in another way. However, with the code below, the program always tells me that my `b` and `c` are unused. But I already used them in `printf`. I don't know what the error is. Can anyone explain the principle behind?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float ratio = atof(argv[1]);

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (ratio > 0.0 && ratio <= 1.0)
    {
        float b = 3/4;
        float c = 4/5;
    }
    else if (ratio > 1.0)
    {
        float b = 1;
        float c = 2;
    }

    printf("b and c are %f, %f", b, c);
}
```

Comment: It is because you are defining `b` and `c` inside if or else if clause. Define them outside if clause.

Comment: Elvin, I think you are repeatedly accepting and unaccepting answers to this question. Please let me know if you would appreciate some help or explanation on the topic. If I am wrong please also let me know. In that case some other user probably needs that help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with scopes. If you declare a variable within a scope, it will cease to exists at the end of that scope. Statements within braces, { and } are in the same scope. [Read more here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/)

Do like this:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) return 1;        

    float ratio = atof(argv[1]);

    float b, c;

    if (ratio > 0.0 && ratio <= 1.0) {
        b = 3.0/4;
        c = 4.0/5;
    } else if (ratio > 1.0) {
        b = 1;
        c = 2;
    }

    printf("b and c are %f, %f", b, c);
}
```

I also changed `3/4` to `3.0/4`, because `3/4` will evaluate to `0` because of integer arithmetics.

Another problem with your code was that you checked number of arguments AFTER you convert the first argument to a float. That should be done before.

Answer (score 3):

The variables `b` and `c` which you try to print in the `printf()` line are in fact only defined within the two branches of the `if`. They are therefore not even defined for the `printf()`.

And inside both branches, the `else` and the `then` separately, they are defined and initialised but afterwards never used again. This is the part the compiler complains about in the way you describe.

To fix, create a single definition of both variables local in main, so that all parts of main use the same variable and see a definition.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float ratio = atof(argv[1]); /* see klutts warning on this line */
    float b = 0.0;
    float c = 0.0;

    /* ... */
```

Then delete all the other `float`s witin `main()`. That will turn the initialising  definitions you programmed into write access to the already defined common variables. Otherwise you still create block-local variables, which are not used again outside of the blocks and are not even visible to the `printf()`, which would lead to the `printf()` printing the initialisation values from start of `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
if (ratio > 0.0 && ratio <= 1.0) {
        float b = 3/4;
        float c = 4/5; /* variable b & c scopes ends after this block */
}
printf("b and c are %f, %f", b, c); /* here printf doesn't know about b & c, hence it throws the error */
```

causes two errors namely

> unused variable ‘c’, unused variable ‘b’ and  error: ‘b’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function) error: ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this
>   function)

Because variable `b` and `c` are declared inside `if() { }` block and scope of these two will be inside this block only, not outside, so the `printf()` causes the error as variable `b` and `c` doesn't exist and since variable `b` and `c` are not used inside `if` block it says

> unused variable ‘c’ [-Werror=unused-variable]

To avoid all these errors, declare variable `b` and `c` like

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
        float ratio = atof(argv[1]);
        if (argc != 2) {
                return 1;
        }
        float b = 0, c = 0; /* declare here it self., so that it can be used in both if and else-if block */
        if (ratio > 0.0 && ratio <= 1.0) {
                b = 3./4; /* to get correct arithmetic, use 3. instead of 3 */
                c = 4./5;
        }
        else if (ratio > 1.0) {
                b = 1;
                c = 2;
        }
        printf("b and c are %f, %f", b, c);
        return 0;
}
```